# Setting User State on bot without Activity avaialble

Tags: botframework

Trying to upgrade code from BF 1.x to 3.x and having trouble finding example to convert the following code

```
var client = new ConnectorClient();
var getData = await client.Bots.GetUserDataAsync(Constants.botId, userid);
getData.Data = ar.Serialize();
var resp = await client.Bots.SetUserDataAsync(Constants.botId, userid, getData);               
return Request.CreateResponse(resp);
```

Open to other approaches, but user is given a link to a website from the bot, it includes the user ID in the link, the site then wants to set state in the conversation.

The big problem is client.Bots doesn't exist any longer - state has moved to it's own StateClient but to get a state client it appears you need to have an Activity object

Answer (score 2):

`activity.GetStateClient` is just a helper for getting the right state client for the given channel. The reason why we need this is that most channels use a centralized store, while others might require a channel-specific one (e.g. emulator). For a deeper understanding, I recommend checking out the code of this method in `ActivityEx.cs`.

The direct way of constructing a state client (for most channels) is this:

```
new StateClient(new MicrosoftAppCredentials(microsoftAppId, microsoftAppPassword));
```

See [this](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dd/dbc/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_state_client.html#a69b24f9fc6e84f5f76ecbdf20e4cff12) for an explanation of the parameters.

Comment: Thanks will give that a try